# Зачем нужны <> при реализации конструкторов?

Tags: c#, классы

Как пример, в коде ниже есть класс, в котором реализуется конструктор. В нем в скобках есть подобный код "Action", но совершенно не понятно зачем оно. Не могу найти разъясняющую информацию. Объясните пожалуйста простым языком, что это и для чего нужно или хотя бы ссылку на разъясняющую статью. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    #region Constructor

    public Command(Action<object> action)
    {
        ExecuteDelegate = action;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Про дженерики (обобщения) что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Нет, не знакомо

Comment: Рекомендую вам прочесть пару начальных глав из любой книги по C#. Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0). Лезть без азов в WPF и прочие фреймворки - себе дороже, лишь время потеряете

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае речь идёт о *паттерне* `Команда`, описанном в [классической книге](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/?gclid=CjwKCAiAn5rUBRA3EiwAUCWb2zTPkrKitEd852x0mxfBG5Jl0n9q1HNHYhCvT11ZVR9ZLwdrHgDf5hoCTKcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CMXeqdDRqtkCFQuEGQodg7YH0w) по паттернам. (первая попавшаяся ссылка из Google)

Паттерн `Команда` позволяет *завернуть* действие в объект и затем, например, помещать действия (операции) в очередь, передавать и, в целом, выполнять их не сразу, а когда нужно.

Возникает вопрос, как завернуть действия. Обычно мы описываем действие в виде функции, и сохраняем адрес этой функции. Современные процессоры позволяют осуществлять *косвенный вызов* функций, то есть передавать управление на адрес, размещённый по другому адресу.

Единственное ограничение заключается в том, что все такие функции должны иметь идентичную сигнатуру, то есть количество и тип параметров, а также тип возвращаемого значения.

Таким образом, мы, фактически храним, передаём и помещаем в очередь обычное целое число, которое интерпретируем как адрес функции в адресном пространстве нашего процесса.

C# управляемый язык, и он немного защищает нас от такой сверхгибкой конструкции. Он вводит тип данных, как *делегат* для того, чтобы единообразно обрабатывать статические методы классов, методы экземпляров классов и даже коллекции этих методов. Кроме того, он строго следит за соблюдением сигнатур.

Вы можете описать тип `Foo` как делегат:

```
delegate void Foo(int a);
```

В переменную такого типа можно будет поместить несколько указателей на методы, которые получают целое число и ничего не возвращают.

```
private void Print(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

private void Print2(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(2 * number);
}

. . .

Foo foo;
foo += Print; // на самом деле здесь всё сложнее, но пока можно считать, что всё просто
foo += Print2;
foo(5); // напечатает 5 на первой строке и 10 на второй
```

Важные аспекты: все методы должны иметь одинаковую сигнатуру. Эта сигнатура совпадает с сигнатурой делегата. Вызов делегата выглядит как вызов метода, но на самом деле он приводит к вызову всех методов, которые добавлены в делегат.

Теперь посмотрим на тип `Action<T>`. Он описан так:

```
delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

Угловые скобки в данном случае говорят о том, что тип обобщённый, то есть вместо `T` потом можно будет подставить конкретный тип. Фактически, мы описали
делегат с сигнатурой *один параметр какого-то типа и никаких возвращаемых значений*.

```
public Command(Action<object> action)
{
    ExecuteDelegate = action;
}
```

Здесь в качестве параметра мы получаем делегат, который специализирован типом `object`, то есть полный тип делегата `Action<object>`. Если вспомнить сигнатуру, это означает, что сюда мы можем передать любой метод, который принимает параметр типа `object` и ничего не возвращает. Мы сохраняем этот метод в свойстве `ExecuteDelegate`. Впоследствии мы можем в любой момент выполнить действие с помощью метода `Execute`:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    ExecuteDelegate(parameter);
}
```

Наконец, отвечаю на ваш вопрос. В реализации паттерна `Команда` используется такая возможность языка C# как *делегаты*. Благодаря обобщённому программированию в C# можно использовать такой тип как `Action<T>` для описания целой группы делегатов: все методы с одним параметром, не возвращающие никакого значения. В паттерне `Команда` используется конкретная специализация обобщённого типа, а именно `Action<object>` которая соответствует методам с одним параметром типа `object`. Угловые скобки это лексемы, с помощью которых в C# обозначаются обобщённые типы — как описания, так и специализации.